# Wrap img inside flexbox with div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, object-fit

I have the following code to simulate `object-fit:contain` for IE compatibility.

```css
.cbs-Item {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.cbs-Item img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cbs-Item img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbs-Item">
  <img src="https://www.imgacademy.com/themes/custom/imgacademy/images/helpbox-contact.jpg" />
</div>
```

I want to wrap the `img` inside a div while making everything look the same. How can I achieve that?

Comment: flexbox is not supported in IE by the way :)

Comment: So, do you want it so that the grey background isn't shown on screen, and hidden?